# Using validation data after early stopping

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, regularization

A common technique to do early stopping is to split the data to 3 parts: *train*, *validation* and *test*, and train on *train* set. After each epoch (or every K epochs) of training we check the loss of the model on the *validation* set, and if this loss doesn't improve for a prespecified number epochs (the exact number is the *patience* hyperparameter), we stop and choose the model with the best validation loss so far. This algorithm is described in section 7.8 of the [deep learning book](http://www.deeplearningbook.org).

[image: alg 7.1]

Next, the book discusses two approaches to reuse the *validation* set to further improve the model. The first (7.2) is to discard the trained parameters and start training from scratch, this time on both *train* and *validation*, using the ideal number of epochs, *i**, from the early stopping stage.

The second (7.3) is to keep the parameters and keep training
on both *train* and *validation*, till the loss on the *validation* set is less than the loss on *train* from the previous step.
[image: alg 7.2]

Frankly, both approaches leave much to be desired for. 7.2 is wasteful by discarding the learned parameters on *train*. Besides there's no guarantee that the number of epochs, *i**, is also optimal for both *train* and *validation*. As for 7.3, first of all, as the book says there's no guarantee for termination as the loss won't necessarily improve. Second, it seems like "self-cheating" if we evaluate on a subset of the training set (recall that we train on *train* and *validation*, and evaluate on *validation*).

Thus, I've thought of a third option: Take the best parameters from the early stopping stage (i.e. 7.1) and continue to train on *train* and *validation*. Stopping when the *training loss* doesn't improve for several epochs. Admittedly, we're interested in the validation loss (i.e. the generalization error) to prevent overfitting, but assuming that *validation* is much smaller than *train*, there will be less updates and thus the model will still be able to generalize. Does this approach make sense? Are there better alternatives?

**Update:** Yoshua Bengio, the author of the book and one of the founding fathers of modern deep learning, has replied regarding my concerns of "cheating" in 7.3:

> You use valid for determining the stopping point while training on subtrain (which excludes valid).
>   Once you have found a stopping point, though, there is nothing wrong in training (up to the stopping point) using the whole of train (= subtrain + valid).

Comment: Instead of putting your answer in the body of your Question, you should use the Answer box below to provide your answer.

Comment: Related questions: (1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/training-with-the-full-dataset-after-cross-validation?noredirect=1&lq=1 (2) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/361494/how-to-correctly-retrain-model-using-all-data-after-cross-validation-with-early (3)https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402403/interplay-between-early-stopping-and-cross-validation/402410#402410 (4) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402055/fitting-after-training-and-validation/402077#402077

Comment: @Sycorax thanks, I'll read these questions carefully.  The update still doesn't answer the main question: does the proposed method make sense. Even if 7.3 isn't "cheating"  it still might not terminate.